# Kendo Ui Form Validation: Use field title in validation message

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Popup grid and notice that the validation message for all the fields that are set to required appear as **"{field} is required"**. I want to be able to use the "Title" field of the model instaed of the fieldname. Is there an easy way for this?

As per Kendo forum http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html : I need to specify the error message individually for all the fields which is not a good solution(IMHO).

Comment: So you can use a custom function for validation and make it as a common one

Comment: you can pass `validationMessage` in your control like this,   `validationMessage="Your message"`.Ex:   
` <input type="text" id="search" name="search" required validationMessage="Search is required"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported out of the box. You need to set the validation message via the `validationMessage` attribute.